# LINQ query with addition to WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to run the following LINQ query twice but with an addition to the Where clause:

```
var TickList = 
    (from comp in Companies
    join eqRes in Equity_issues on comp.Ticker equals eqRes.Ticker
    where !comp.Coverage_status.Contains("dropp") 
        && !comp.Coverage_status.Contains("Repla") && eqRes.Primary_equity.Equals('N')
     select new 
    {
        LocalTick = eqRes.Local_ticker.Trim(),
        Exchange = eqRes.Exchange_code.Contains("HKSE") ? "HK" : (eqRes.Exchange_code.Contains("NSDQ") ? "NASDQ" : eqRes.Exchange_code),
        Ticker = comp.Ticker.Trim()
    }).ToList();
```

This query works fine, but I need to pass an additional parameter to the Where clause:

```
where !comp.Coverage_status.Contains("dropp") 
        && !comp.Coverage_status.Contains("Repla") && eqRes.Primary_equity.Equals('N')
        && !comp.Coverage_status.Contains("Intl")  <--- new addition
```

Is there a way to do this without being DRY?  Isn't there an efficient way of doing this without repeating the query with the new addition?

Comment: Use PredicateBuilder from [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
// select additional Intl field (similar to Exchange)
var TickList = 
    (from comp in Companies
    join eqRes in Equity_issues on comp.Ticker equals eqRes.Ticker
    where !comp.Coverage_status.Contains("dropp") 
        && !comp.Coverage_status.Contains("Repla") && eqRes.Primary_equity.Equals('N')
     select new 
    {
        LocalTick = eqRes.Local_ticker.Trim(),
        Exchange = eqRes.Exchange_code.Contains("HKSE") ? "HK" : (eqRes.Exchange_code.Contains("NSDQ") ? "NASDQ" : eqRes.Exchange_code),
        Intl = comp.Coverage_status.Contains("Intl") ? 1 : 0,
        Ticker = comp.Ticker.Trim()
    }).ToList();

// use LINQ to objects to filter results of the 1st query
var intl = TickList.Where(x => x.Intl = 0).ToList();
```

Comment: This solution is slightly wet.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below if you want to be DRY:

```
var keywords = new string[] { "dropp", "Repla", "Intl" };

var TickList = Companies
    .Join(Equity_issues, c => c.Ticker, e => e.Ticker, (c, e) => new { c, e })
    .Where(ce => ce.e.Primary_equity.Equals('N')
                 && keywords.All(v => !ce.c.Coverage_status.Contains(v)))
    .Select(ce => new 
     {
        LocalTick = ce.e.Local_ticker.Trim(),
        Exchange = ce.e.Exchange_code.Contains("HKSE")
                   ? "HK"
                   : (ce.e.Exchange_code.Contains("NSDQ")
                     ? "NASDQ"
                     : ce.e.Exchange_code),
        Ticker = ce.c.Ticker.Trim()
     })
    .ToList();
```

Now you can run this query with any combination of keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Probably overkill here but there have been situations where I've created a full blown query object that internally held an IQueryable and used methods on the object to add the where clause (mostly for letting users filter and sort their results)

```
public class TickList{
    IQueryable<Foo> _query;
    public TickList(){
        _query = from comp in Companies
                 join eqRes in Equity_issues on comp.Ticker equals eqRes.Ticker
                 select new Foo {
                     LocalTick = eqRes.Local_ticker.Trim(),
                     Exchange = eqRes.Exchange_code.Contains("HKSE") ? "HK" :(eqRes.Exchange_code.Contains("NSDQ") ? "NASDQ" : eqRes.Exchange_code),
                     Ticker = comp.Ticker.Trim()
                 };
    }
    public void WhereCoverageContains(string text){
        _query = _query.Where(x => x.Coverage_Status.Contains(text));
    }
    public void WherePrimaryEquityIs(string text){
        _query = _query.Where(x => x.PrimaryEquity.Equals(text));
    }
    public List<Foo> ToList(){
        return _query.ToList();
    }
}
```

It's super verbose so use with caution.  Sometimes it's possible to be too dry.